# MEF and AssemblyCatalog / AggregateCatalog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mef, aggregate

I have a simple console app as below (un-relevant code removed for simplicity)

```
    [ImportMany(typeof(ILogger))]
    public IEnumerable<ILogger> _loggers {get;set;}

    public interface ILogger
    {
        void Write(string message);
    }

    [Export(typeof(ILogger))]
    public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void Write(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }

    [Export(typeof(ILogger))]
    public class DebugLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void Write(string message)
        {
            Debug.Print(message);
        }
    }
```

The code that initialize the catalog is below

```
(1) var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
(2) catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
(3) //var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
var batch = new CompositionBatch();
batch.AddPart(this);
container.Compose(batch);
```

If the catalog is initialized trough lines 1-2, nothing got loaded into _logger 
If the catalog is initialized trough line 3, both logger got loaded into _logger

What's the issue with AggregateCatalog approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It seems DirectoryCatalog(path) search only in DLL by default, and my test program was a console application. And the exports were in EXE (not DLL) so they weren't loaded.

On the other hand, AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()), obviously loaded exports from current assembly(which is the EXE).

The solution is to use the other constructor of DirectoryCatalog(path, searchPattern) , and use "*.*" for second param. And it works

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you are using it.

However, on line 2 you are creating a DirectoryCatalog, and on line 3 an AssemblyCatalog. Does it work as expected if you change line two into

```
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
```

Comment: Thanks. But I would expect line DirectoryCatalog(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) adds to the catalog exports from all DLL's in app's bin folder (which is what I actually want at some point). Unlike AssemblyCatalog, which just adds exports from current Assembly. How to look for exports in all DLL's?